# Why does not work child route for component?

Tags: angular

File `AppRoutingModule` contains:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "events",
    component: EventComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddEventComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I try to reach `AddEventComponent` by url: `localhost:4200/events/add`

It is not opened, without errors.

Component `AddEventComponent` was registered in `add-event.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/SharedModule';
import { CompanyService } from 'src/app/api/CompanyService';
import { AddEventComponent } from './add-event-component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [AddEventComponent],
  exports: [AddEventComponent],
  providers: [CompanyService]
})
export class AddEventModule { }
```

Then `AddEventModule` was added to main `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
     AddEventModule
]});
```

So,I need to open component `AddEventComponent` by url: `localhost:4200/events/add`, now it always opens parent `EventComponent`

**AppModule**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NofoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    LoginModule,
    LanguageModule,
    EventModule,
    AddEventModule,
    VisitorModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: CustomTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),

    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RequestInterception,
    multi: true,
  },
    EventsService, VisitorsService, UserService, ExportService, AuthenticationGuard],
  exports: [TranslateModule, AddEventModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `EventComponent`? Also where is `AppRoutingModule` imported?

Comment: I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component

Comment: Please show where/how `AppRoutingModule` is imported in your application. Also where is `EventComponent` declared?

Comment: `EventComponent` declared in `EventModule` and module imported in `AppModule`?

Comment: You should please update your question to reflect that. Currently `EventComponent` and `AppRoutingModule` are not imported anywhere in your question's code.

Comment: Try now adding a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the template of `EventComponent` and see if that makes a difference. Which you need anywhere you use child routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your component `EventComponent` add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as you are using [child routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component). This is needed to render routes/components defined in the `children` route configuration property.

EventComponent:

```
<!-- existing component content -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

With this, any components specified in `children` would render **within** `EventComponent` in place of the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

If you weren't using the `children` property in the route configuration, then you would not need an additional `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `EventComponent`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "events", component: EventComponent },
  { path: "events/add", component: AddEventComponent }
];
```

With that however, `AddEventComponent` would not render **within** `EventComponent`, but **instead** of `EventComponent`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Do you mean if I use `children` it means parent component should have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: @OPV Yes, that's exactly correct. It needs `<router-outlet>` to render any `children`.